# Why does Travis CI kill the process for my script?

Tags: android, yaml, travis-ci

I added the following configuration to run [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org) on the [Fahrplan](https://github.com/johnjohndoe/CampFahrplan) Android project:

```yaml
language: android

android:
  components:

  # All the build system components should be at the latest version
  # - tools
  # - platform-tools
  - build-tools-21.1.1
  - android-19
  - sysimg-19
  - add-on
  - extra

  # The libraries we can't get from Maven Central or similar
  - extra-android-support
  - extra-android-m2repository

jdk:
  - oraclejdk7
  - openjdk7

notifications:
  email: true

before_script:
  - chmod +x gradlew
  - mv app/gradle.properties.example app/gradle.properties

script:
  - ./gradlew clean assembleDebug
```

For some reason the process gets killed again and again as can be seen in the [build history](https://travis-ci.org/johnjohndoe/CampFahrplan/builds). It stops at different locations. The error message is not that informative:

> The command "./gradlew clean assembleDebug" exited with 137

Answer (score 2):

Only checking the gradle version you can force the download before you run the script (helps me to avoid error 137) but now i use `wrapper` so gradle-wrapper.jar is updated.

If it doesn't work, you can try to download the android dependencies before to run the script and clean before too.

I think they don't assemble by default but I like to override install stage to be sure.

In my case, error 137 is due concurrency (build/emulator) and jobs killed by Travis-ci. I solve it doing changes of this type and I don't understand it very well.

```
language: android

jdk:
  - oraclejdk7
  - openjdk7

android:
  components:

    # All the build system components should be at the latest version
    - tools
    - platform-tools
    - build-tools-21.1.1
    - android-19

    # The libraries we can't get from Maven Central or similar
    - extra-android-support
    - extra-android-m2repository


notifications:
  email: true

before_install:
  # Disable services enabled by default
  # http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/database-setup/#MySQL
  - sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
  - sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql stop
  # The following did not work reliable
  # - sudo service mysql stop
  # - sudo service postgresql stop

install:
  # Ensure Gradle wrapper is executable, download wrapper and show version
  - chmod +x ./gradlew; ls -l gradlew; ./gradlew wrapper -v
  # Download and show android dependencies
  # - ./gradlew androidDependencies

before_script:        
  # Ensure signing configuration is present
  - mv app/gradle.properties.example app/gradle.properties

script:
  - ./gradlew clean assembleDebug
```

Comment: As you have taken my script I think it works better since I am stopping the database processes to free resources. Let's see how it works for some weeks.

Comment: I'll try your second stop method, the first did not work for me either. Another option is decrease these values `GRADLE_OPTS="-Xmx768m -Xms256m -Xss1m`.

Comment: @Ardock `GRADLE_OPTS="-Xmx768m -Xms256m -Xss1m"` solved the problem for me. Thanks. TravisCI container builds have a 3G memory limit.

Comment: @easyspeak I am at a loss here, can you please explain how decreasing the memory solves this issue. I was assuming we will have to increase the heap size?